# Can't make microphone work on Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, microphone, netstream

A Adobe Flex issue...

I'm attaching a microphone to a NetStream, but there is no mic activity. The privacy is set to Allow, the microphone.muted is false and the activity level is -1.

Only when I open the flash settings, and open the Microphone tab, it starts to dispatch the Activity events, and it starts to stream the audio.

Also, when I start to loopBack it starts working. But I don't want loopBack.

Did you have the same problem? I hope I was clear.

Comment: Well, I would like... but the code is huge and it's not opensource :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found what is the problem!

Just before I attached the microphone to the NetStream object, I was doing setLoopBack(false)

When I commented that code it started streaming the audio right away.

I have done that because in some test versions I needed to LoopBack. I was stuck because I was setting loopback to false. I just needed to comment it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you called `getMicrophone` properly? The documentation clearly states:

> If the microphone is available but is
>   not yet being used because
>   Microphone.getMicrophone() has not
>   been called, this property is set to
>   -1.

You have to initialize the microphone, like so: `myMic = Microphone.getMicrophone()`.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, it works perfectly in the last stable version. Now I will remove the activity event handlers and go back some versions. SVN is a huge help, but there is nothing evident what I messed up...